# Getting list of data with Ruby Symbols

Tags: ruby, symbols, hash

Im trying to get a list of data from a ruby data file. I have the code like this:

```
us_cities = {:city => 'Lewisville', 'Florida', 'Angeles'}
```

Im doing self studies and Im trying to use less memory. But as I hit the enter button I get an error message. I want when I do this: `us_cities[:city]`
I get the list of cities. Am I going it the correct way?

If you could answer with a doc reference so I can read would be lovely. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Hash`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Hash.html) object holds list of key-vaue pairs, where each key-value pair is separated by comma(`,`). Your one is errorneous, rather do as a below :

```
us_cities = {:city => ['Lewisville', 'Florida', 'Angeles']}
us_cities[:city] # => ['Lewisville', 'Florida', 'Angeles']
```

> A `Hash` is a dictionary-like collection of unique keys and their values. Also called associative arrays, they are similar to Arrays, but where an Array uses integers as its index, a Hash allows you to use any object type.Hashes enumerate their values in the order that the corresponding keys were inserted.

I have created a `us_cities` hash, which has a single key `:city` and value to that key is an Array object, which hold all the list of city names. Now to get the value of that key `:city`, we need to use [`Hash#[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D)(exactly what we did here `us_cities[:city]`).